# Run <script> on AJAX loaded enement

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page that loads some of its content through `JQUERY.get`.

```
<html>
   <body>
       <div onclick="foo('example.com')">Click here!!!</div>
       <div id="replacePanel"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Need to load the content

```
<div id="replacePanel">
    <div id="moveAccordion" class="grid_12">
        <h3>From</h3>

        <div>
            <p>
                <label class="label">From:</label>

            </p>
        </div>
        <h3>To</h3>
        <div>
            <p style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <label class="label">To:</label>
            </p>
        </div>
        <h3>Delta</h3>
        <div>
            <p>
                <label class="label">delta time:</label>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script> 
            $('#moveAccordion').accordion();
    </script>
</div>
```

JQuery AJAX function:

```
function foo(url){
    $.get(url, function(response) {
        $('#replacePanel').replaceWith($('#replacePanel',response));
    }
}
```

It should load a jQuery UI accordion, But it loads only the HTML part, and it does not call the `<script>` that creates the UI.

Can you please tell me how I can use JavaScript to run that script?
I think it might have to do with some JavaScript events.

Comment: Perhaps this helps you out: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ - would have to do some refactoring of your scripts but it should work

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? This doesnt make much sense

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you have an event listener attached that loads the content via ajax? If that assumption is correct, you should use `on` to add the event handler. This works if you have jQuery > 1.7 - if your version is older use `live` to add the event handler instead.

See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Well, according to your own comment below you add it to an outside element, add it to that one. `$('some element').on('click', function(){ ...your ajax request here... })`;

Comment: but request is good. response saves needed div to my page. but scripts in that div are not triggered. maybe we do not understand each other.

Answer (score 0):

dont include your  `<script>$('#moveAccordion').accordion();</script>` in your **response** variable, try transferring your `<script> $('#moveAccordion').accordion();</script>` before your `</body>` tag

Comment: my trigger is element.onClick on outside element

Comment: what data should your response variable return? and what would you like to replace in replacepanel?

Comment: response will terurn jquery UI accordion with init script. And i need show that accordion rendered.

Comment: move your '<script> $('#moveaccordion').accordion(); </script>' outside your replacepannel, place it before your `</body>` tag